# connecting primary cells in parallel

Tags: batteries

I want to make a holder for 2S2P(2 series, 2 parallel) non-rechargeable AA cells. Connection should be easy, because there are a lot of 2S1P holders . But I'm worried about the possibility that current flows from 2 cells to other 2 cells.

(1) If the voltage of two 2S1P cells are 2.8V, 2.5V respectively, should I expect that I will have a short circuit? In other words, could current flow from 2.8V battery to 2.5V battery?
(2) If so, could I avoid such situation by putting connecting diodes to the 2S1P cells? Would the diodes consume power?

Comment: Before connecting cells in parallel, you need to **balance** them. That could be as simple as connecting them in parallel **not directly** but with a resistor (2 ohms perhaps) instead of a straight wire. That resistor will limit the current to a safe value. After an hour or less the voltages of the cells should be quite similar and then it is safe to connect them together in parallel without a resistor. Using diodes is not a good idea as it will interfere with charging and result in a voltage drop. Also, it is not needed once the cells are balanced.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The question is about primary cells

Comment: OK, that was unclear as 2S2P etc. is normally only used in relation to rechargeable cells. Then forget about the balancing! You can put primary cells in parallel when you make sure they have identical charge. That's when they're new, unused and coming out of the same package. Again I would not recommend using diodes as that will give you a voltage drop. Unless you **insist** on being able to use batteries with different charge levels. But then use **Schottky diodes** to limit the voltage drop.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thank you! I expected that there would be a small difference among same products, in particular they are stored for a long time. Except the power dissipation issue, it seems fine to connect cells with different terminal voltages? I would use a  Schottky diode or a MOSFET to prevent reverse current.

Comment: I updated my question to avoid the confusion on recharge-ability.

Comment: Using larger cells is usually a better idea than putting smaller cells in parallel, especially in a consumer device.

Comment: Instead of using AA in parallel cells you could consider using C cells if space is not an issue. Or you could consider using the newer Lithium type AA cells, these are also 1.5 V but have a larger capacity (more energy).

Answer (score 1):

Connecting cells in parallel will cause current to flow between/around/through the cells.  This is bad because it wastes the power (reduces the life) of the higher voltage cell, and, for non-rechargeable primary cells, makes the low voltage cell more likely to leak (fail, burst), and voids any warranty the cell manufacturer provides.

Putting a diode in series with each string reduces the available voltage, and wastes power, but it is better than allowing reverse current through a non-rechargeable cell.